# Creating an javascript graph with marker that is synchronize with a movie

Tags: javascript, char, google-visualization, html5-video, dygraphs

I'm trying to create an online web tool for eeg signal analysis. The tool suppose to display a graph of an eeg signal synchronize with a movie that was display to a subject.

I've already implemented it successfully on csharp but I can't find a way to do it easily with any of the know javascript chart that I saw.

A link of a good tool that do something similar can be found here:

http://www.mesta-automation.com/real-time-line-charts-with-wpf-and-dynamic-data-display/

I've tried using dygraph, and google chart. I know that it should be relatively easy to create an background thread on the server that examine the movie state every ~50ms. What I was not able to do is to create a marker of the movie position on the chart itself dynamically. I was able to draw on the dygraph but was not able to change the marker location.

just for clarification, I need to draw a vertical line as a marker.

I'm in great suffering. Please help :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "a marker ... on the chart itself dynamically". Can you clarify? Do you want to select a point? Draw a vertical line?

Comment: I need to draw a vertical line.

Comment: Here's a demo of drawing a vertical rectangle on a dygraph. You could probably adapt it: http://dygraphs.com/tests/highlighted-region.html

Comment: Thanks. I've actually tried to use this demo. The problem it that I can't find a way to move the yellow line dynamically. The demo is drawing a yellow rectanlge on the canvas. I need to redraw the line in different position  every 50ms. This is something that I didn't figure out how to do yet.

Comment: You could clear the canvas and redraw every frame. You'd be surprised how good the performance is!

Comment: I've tried to clear it using the following code but it also clear the graph itslef(here is a jsfiddler link [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ng9vy8mb/)http://jsfiddle.net/ng9vy8mb/:

Comment: Thanks. I've actually did a small prototype of it but it seems to work. At least when not using zoom in and out. I'll try to write a complete working example and then post it here under the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Danvk I figure out how to do it.
Below is a jsfiddler links that demonstrate such a solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/ng9vy8mb/10/embedded/result/

below is the javascript code that do the task. It changes the location of the marker in synchronizing with the video.

There are still several improvement that can be done.

1. Currently, if the user had zoomed in the graph and then click on it, the zoom will be reset.
2. there is no support for you tube movies
   I hope that soon I can post a more complete solution that will also enable user to upload the graph data and video from their computer

;

```
 var dc;
 var g;
 var v;

 var my_graph;

 var my_area;

 var current_time = 0;
//when the document is done loading, intialie the video events listeners
 $(document).ready(function () {
     v = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
     v.onseeking = function () {
             current_time = v.currentTime * 1000;
             draw_marker();
         };

     v.oncanplay = function () {
         CreateGraph();             
         };

     v.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (event) {
         var t = document.getElementById('time');
         t.innerHTML = v.currentTime;
         g.updateOptions({
             isZoomedIgnoreProgrammaticZoom: true
         });

         current_time = v.currentTime * 1000;
     }, false);         
 });

 function change_movie_position(e, x, points) {
     v.currentTime = x / 1000;
 }

 function draw_marker() {
     dc.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)";
     var left = my_graph.toDomCoords(current_time, 0)[0] - 2;
     var right = my_graph.toDomCoords(current_time + 2, 0)[0] + 2;
     dc.fillRect(left, my_area.y, right - left, my_area.h);
 };


//data creation
 function CreateGraph() {
     number_of_samples = v.duration * 1000;
     // A basic sinusoidal data series.
     var data = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < number_of_samples; i++) {
         var base = 10 * Math.sin(i / 90.0);
         data.push([i, base, base + Math.sin(i / 2.0)]);
     }

     // Shift one portion out of line.
     var highlight_start = 450;
     var highlight_end = 500;
     for (var i = highlight_start; i <= highlight_end; i++) {
         data[i][2] += 5.0;
     }

     g = new Dygraph(
     document.getElementById("div_g"),
     data, {
         labels: ['X', 'Est.', 'Actual'],
         animatedZooms: true,
         underlayCallback: function (canvas, area, g) {
             dc = canvas;
             my_area = area;
             my_graph = g;
             bottom_left = g.toDomCoords(0, 0);
             top_right = g.toDomCoords(highlight_end, +20);
             draw_marker();
         }
     });

     g.updateOptions({
         clickCallback: change_movie_position
     }, true);

 }
```